# Change UIbuttons color after it has been created

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've created a series of buttons and added them to the view, I was hoping to be able to access these buttons somehow and change their appearance.

This is the two versions of code that i have tried, while I'm confident that it is locating the correct button nothing seems to happen to its background color.

```
  for(UIView *v in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            if (buttonTag == [v tag]) {
                v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [[self.view subviews] count]; i++) {
        if ([[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] class] == [UIButton class]) {
            NSLog(@"Tags : %i", [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] tag]);
            if (buttonTag == [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] tag]) {

                [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: in your first version can you take out buttonTag check for a moment and see if it works?

Comment: but i'm creating the buttons programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say that your first code version works for me, provided buttonTag's value is correct.

To debug, I suggest that you comment out the buttonTag comparison and just turn all your buttons red.

It may be that your button is not at the top level of your UIView hierarchy. It may be embedded in a subview. If so, you could put your loop into a recursive function.

Or, it may be that your UIButton backgroundColor is turned red, and you just can't see it. The interior of a rounded-rect button will remain white; only the areas outside the rounded corners will show red. A button with a background image might also cover any red.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

1. You can set selected property for example

   if(myButtton.selected = YES)
   {
    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   }
   Also the highlighted properties are available as myBUtton.highlighted = YES;

OR

1. You can set the background image or background color as follows:
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imagedNamed:strechableImage] forState:UIControlStateTouchUpInside];

   or for the normal state as:
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imagedNamed:strechableImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Well the thing is that im not actually selecting the button, something else is being clicked which will change the color of the button

Comment: Then you can probably use 

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if([touch view] == theaTouchesView)